# Is it true that $I+J\subseteq I\cap J$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I,J$ are ideals in $R$. Is it true that

$$I+J\subseteq I\cap J?$$

I know that $I+J =\{x+y|x\in I, y\in J\}$.

Comment: It is the other way around

Comment: This holds if and only if $I=J.$

Comment: I've thought about a counterexample. Let $R=\mathbb{Z}, I=6\mathbb{Z} , J=4\mathbb{Z}$. Then:

$$6\mathbb{Z}+4\mathbb{Z}=\text{gcd}(6,4)\mathbb{Z}=2\mathbb{Z}\not\subset 12\mathbb{Z}=\text{lcm}(6,4)\mathbb{Z}=6\mathbb{Z}\cap 4\mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: But I didn't have these rules, i.e. under addition, I should use gcd, and under intersection lcm. Is there a easier way to give a counterexample without gcd and lcm?

Answer (score 2):

In general: 
$$I\cap J\subseteq I\subseteq I+J.$$
The converse is true if and only if $I=J.$  One direction is obvious. for the other:
Let $I+J\subseteq I\cap J.$
Then $\forall a\in I,\ a=a+0\in I+J \subseteq I\cap J.$ So $\forall a\in I, a\in J.$ Hence $I\subseteq J.$ Similarly $J\subseteq I.$ Therefore, in this case we should have $I=J$.